# How to convert Mongo db type from String to Object type for existing document

Tags: spring, mongodb

I am using Spring, mango db and mongock. When I started working on project hen Mongo entity has one column (Address) of type String. But now its type is changed to string to Address object. Like below code.
Now this solution is working for new entity perfectly fine but when try to get existing

Old Code :

```
@Document(collection = PersistenceConstants.TALENT_COLLECTION)
    public class Talent extends AbstractMongoEntity<String>{
        private String address;
    }
```

New Code :

```
@Document(collection = PersistenceConstants.TALENT_COLLECTION)
    public class Talent extends AbstractMongoEntity<String>{
        private Address address;
    }

{"city","", "country":"India"}
```

But when trying to fetch old records, system throws

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type
```

Could someone tell me , what is work around to fix this issue.

Comment: I think you should migrate all Talent Document to new Talent2 Document with correct format, after that use it instead of Talent Document. :)

Answer (score 0):

this is basically what Mongock is for. You are facing a data migration issue.
So the solution is to create a Mongock ChangeLog(the migration unit) to transform the old talent documents in MongoDB to the new Document structure. Then you're safe to work with your new Talent repository as all your documents would have the new structure.

The steps would be something like.

1. Extract all your documents from talent collection
2. Check the address field of all the documents, if it's a string, transform it to your new structure.
3. Bulk update for all those amended documents.

Then you need to take into account the possibility of failure. Mongock now supports transactions, so if you are using them, you are fine.

If not, you need to design your changelog taking some considerations. [This link](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock/blob/master/community/README_V3.md#mongo-transaction-limitations) gives you some context.

Also worthy to take a look to [Mongock's documentation](https://www.mongock.io).

Mongock latest version at this moment is 4.1.15